# Can an EJB access methods of standalone java application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

I have a standalone java application that initializes and establishes socket connections, both server and client.  The standalone java application have operations such as startConnection, stopConnection, getConnectionStatus, etc.

I would like to develop EJB to access or invoke the standalone java application operations, such as getConnectionStatus. The EJB will be deployed to Glassfish.

If the EJB can access the java application and receive results, would you provide an example, references, and/or implementation strategies?

Comment: How are the operations exposed to potential clients? Standard Java RMI?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder...The RMI approach is just what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are trying to do.

You can either create some EJB(s) and include the classes that your application uses in your .jar file, or package that application's jar into your EJB's (.ear or .war) file (depending on how you are deploying).  This would statically link the code which runs with a "standalone" application with your EJB(s).

Alternatively, you can add some remote invocation methods to your standalone application and turn it into a server that can accept commands.  To do that, you can look at Hessian which can allow you to remote services in your application.  Here is one example that I found:  https://karussell.wordpress.com/2009/04/10/hessian-web-service-protocol-hello-world-example/